# How to add admin chat UI using smooch?

Tags: smooch

I'm looking forward to implement chat window for admin where admin can reply to all customers. I am able to integrate chat with slack channel where admin can reply,But I couldn't find any inbuilt tool/plugin(web) available to implement that. Also didn't find any way to create a group chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably guessed, Smooch is a platform that hooks up with popular chat systems and CRMs that already exist, such as Slack. However, Smooch itself is not a CRM, there is no Smooch admin chat UI.

It is entirely possible to build your own admin chat UI for Smooch. The first place to start would be our [REST API docs](http://docs.smooch.io/rest/).

In fact, the amazing team of developers at [Front](https://frontapp.com/) did this themselves this past February. You can give their Smooch integration a test drive [here](https://faq.frontapp.com/11682-Adding-a-New-Inbox-in-Front/how-to-add-a-smooch-inbox-in-front).

To answer your question about group chats: Smooch's model supports having many agents join the conversation on the business side, but a Smooch conversation is only designed to connect to a single end user identity. Note that an end user may use multiple different devices/clients to connect to a Smooch conversation (eg Facebook, SMS, etc) all end user clients connected to a conversation are considered to be owned by the same end user identity. You can find more info on how this currently works [here](http://docs.smooch.io/javascript/#users-on-multiple-devices).